# How to get auth token for Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-custom-search

I'm trying to create a Google custom search engine programatically. Therefore I have to sent the GET request as described in this link.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api

```
GET http://www.google.com/cse/api/<USER_ID>/cse/<CSE_ID>
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=IM6F7Cx2fo0TAiwlhNVdSE8Ov8hw6aHV
```

Here they mentioned auth token. How can I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you linked [Custom Search - autentication](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api#auth)

Although the Accounts Authentication API supports multiple authentication methods, Custom Search only supports [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps)

Answer: You get the access token back from client login.

What I would like to know is what will happen when client login stops working and if this will work with OAuth2. If it does work with OAuth2 why haven't they added documentation for it.   I am sending some feed back on that page, its really outdated.

Comment: @DalmTo, Thanks for your response, According your answer it is not possible to create Google Custom Search Engine programatically?

Comment: you might be able to if you had the hard coded login and password.

Comment: @DalmTo, Even I hard coded, Can I create Custom Search Engine programatically?, Because [ClientLogin] also deprecated by Google. (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps)

Comment: ClientLogin is now deprecated and oauth doesn't seem to work. Did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: ClientAuth has been turned off. Has anyone figured out if there's a way to use Google CSE API at all anymore?  Has Google just stopped supporting CSE API with the sunsetting of ClientAuth?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question, especially since ClientLogin is now deprecated, so I asked Google support and this was the response:

"Hi,

Greetings from Google for Work Support Team!

As i understand from your message, you are trying to use GSS features programmatically, i would like to update you that GSS supported only client login authentication to access search engine and its features programmatically, but client login is deprecated and it no longer works with GSS.

Oauth 2.0 is also currently not supported with GSS.

We already have a feature request #6043481 to provide support for Oauth 2.0 with GSS. However i don't have an ETA when it will be implemented.

Due to this reason, currently adding promotion programmatically is not possible. I would recommend you to use search engine control panel and respective features manually by opening GSS control panel in browser and update promotion from GSS control panel->Search Feature-> Promotions-> Add as per your requirement.

Please check the same from your end and let me know if you need any further assistance with this."

tl;dr: This is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they've removed this functionality altogether instead of fixing it so auth is possible. There are no longer docs at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api , it 404s.

Comment: I asked this question 2 years ago. That time, that page was there. Now they have removed.